# KDE Kubuntu System Monitor ProcessTable.sgrd and SystemLoad2.sgrd malformed XML

Tags: kde, kubuntu

When trying to open the System Monitor, I received an error saying that the files  `ProcessTable.sgrd` and `SystemLoad2.sgrd` contain malformed XML. The resource graphs no longer appeared after the program loaded.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder...

```
/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/.kde/share/apps/ksysguard/
```

I created a folder and moved the two files in to it in case it caused even worse problems. When I started System Monitor the graphs showed up again.

Apparently files in your own home directory are safe to delete if you did not create them.

Comment: For the most part... they're safe to delete even if you DID create them.  You might be upset with yourself later though. Hee Hee